# There was an error in your Gemfile and Bundler cannot continue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just did a bundle update, and now when I run 'rails s' I get the classic 'There was an error in your Gemfile, and Bundler cannot continue.' with no other output. The Gemfile itself hasn't had a checkin in a while, nothing really seems to have changed.

Can anyone spot a problem in the below Gemfile? Or any tips on how to get more verbose output from rails s? Could the problem be in the Gemfile.lock?

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'rails', '~> 3.2'                  # web framework
gem 'pg'                               # PostgreSQL driver
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'compass-rails'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end

group :development do
  gem 'heroku'
  gem 'taps'
  gem 'foreman'
  gem 'awesome_print'
end

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
```

Comment: have you run bundle install also after update..?

Comment: There really is no harm in deleting your Gemfile.lock and then just re-running bundle from the terminal. However, did you check your development.log file for anything more? By default, Rails is pretty verbose when outputting to the console/log in development mode.

Answer (score 0):

Try this once

```
bundle exec rails s
```